# Groupby dataframe where fuzzy match greater or equal to 80

Tags: dataframe, pandas-groupby, fuzzywuzzy

I'm trying to group the same rows if the rows have equal or more then 0.8 fuzzy match.

Here is my dataframe.

```
    name   age   gender
 0  bob    15    Male
 1  Sara   15    Female
 2  bob    17    Male
```

I want following output

```
    name   age   gender   cluster id  match
 0  bob    15    Male     1           .96
 1  bob    17    Male     1           .96
 2  Sara   15    Female   2
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I searched for solutions to this problem but could not find any. So I created one by myself. Here's my solution. [medium](https://medium.com/@imfaizanahmed/group-similar-rows-of-a-pyspark-dataframe-on-basis-of-the-fuzzy-ratio-2bf2194c8901) PS: lets me know if you find any issue or if you have any improvement.